# $\int^1_0(1-x)^8x^{11}-(1-x)^{11}x^8dx$ and replacing variables

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find $$\int^1_0(1-x)^8x^{11}-(1-x)^{11}x^8dx$$

I have an answer here but I don't understand the last part of it:

$$\int^1_0(1-x)^8x^{11}-(1-x)^{11}x^8dx=\int^1_0(1-x)^8x^{11}dx-\int^1_0(1-x)^{11}x^8dx$$

Take the right most expression, $t=1-x, dx=-dt$ new bounds are flipped:

$$-\int^1_0(1-x)^{11}x^8dx=\int^0_1(t)^{11}(1-t)^8dt=-\int^1_0(t)^{11}(1-t)^8dt\bf=-\int^1_0(1-x)^8x^{11}dx$$

Why can we turn $t$ back to be $x$ like that?

Comment: The x is a dummy variable, basically. We do not really care what variable we use for the integral, since the output itself is a scalar. The only thing to know about $t$ and $x$ in this problem is that they belong to the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Integration variables are mute variables.

Comment: $$t=1-x\implies \begin{cases}x=0\implies t=1-0=1\\ x=1\implies t=1-1=0\end{cases}$$
 
and you already have $\mathrm dx =-\mathrm dt$

Comment: I recently wasted two days on a problem similar to that one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280128/sum-of-integrals-with-variables-shifted-in-each-sum-how-to-justify-this-express

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes to the question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio are the variables mute in indefinite integrals too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx\underset{y=x}{=}\int_a^b f(y)dy\underset{\spadesuit=y}{=}\int_a^b f(\spadesuit)d\spadesuit\underset{\star=\spadesuit}{=}\int_a^b f(\star)d\star\underset{\LaTeX=\star}{=}\int_a^b f(\LaTeX)d\LaTeX=...$$

Comment: LOL $\spadesuit=\LaTeX$. don't forget the $\star$ too.

Comment: you right, I put it :-)

Comment: Is this the same with indefinite integrals too?

Comment: nice solution and graphic to!!!

Comment: @kuhaku yes it is. Another example with [bound variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) is the following:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty }x_k=\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n$$

Comment: it is $$2 x^{19}-19 x^{18}+83 x^{17}-221 x^{16}+400 x^{15}-518 x^{14}+490 x^{13}-338
   x^{12}+166 x^{11}-55 x^{10}+11 x^9-x^8$$